# Need to use query to get value between first dash and second dash from "aaaa-h0321456-f7894-1599-5"

Tags: sybase

Can anyone help me to write a query for below requests?

1. get value of h0321456 between 1st dash and 2nd dash from "aaaa-h0321456-f7894-1599-5"
2. get value of f7894 between 2nd dash and 3rd dash from "aaaa-h0321456-f7894-1599-5"

Thanks very much!

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

/\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-\d+-\d/
$1,$2 should be what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, I need sql query like using substring, charindex, etc. not unix coding.

Comment: I tried this but it's still having some issue.  select column_name,substr(column_name,CHARINDEX('-', column_name)+1,(((LEN(column_name))-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(column_name)))-CHARINDEX('-',column_name)-CHARINDEX('-',column_name)-CHARINDEX('-',column_name)-CHARINDEX('-',column_name))) AS new_column FROM table

Comment: anyone has better idea? please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is Sybase `SQLAnywhere` (or `IQ`) the [regexp_substr()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/17.0/en-US/81fb858e6ce210149d90c9fe24823b1e.html) function may be of interest.

If this is Sybase `ASE`:

- there is no support for regex patterns
- if the version is `15.x/16.x` then a [user defined function (UDF)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/ab44f24fdc2f40ac93b35af5710f8672/16.0.1.0/en-US/a680063cbc2b101491b4e4866a454108.html) is likely the best option to obtain the desired result